# Can not access files owned by other user/group

Tags: permissions, tomcat

I am running tomcat7 on Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance. Previously I could access tomcat log files from Ubuntu user without `sudo`. After installing the latest kernel patch I can not access log files without `sudo`. Tomcat log files are kept in a folder owned by `tomcat:tomcat`.

What should I do to access files under the tomcat log folder from Ubuntu user?